# Use CURL from API

Tags: swift, rest, nsurlsession

I am new with APIs and I am trying to import data from the API of Schiphol Airport. First I tried this link in my query, but then I got the following result.

https://api.schiphol.nl/public-flights/flights?app_id=////APPID////&app_key=////APPKEY////&includedelays=false&page=0&sort=%2Bscheduletime

```
result: {code = 406; description = "Can't retrieve version number from accept-header";}
```

I think that I have to use the CURL to get a result, but I don't know how to do that in SWIFT 3.

```
CURL: curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "ResourceVersion: v3" "https://api.schiphol.nl/public-flights/flights?app_id=////APPID////&app_key=////APPKEY////&includedelays=false&page=0&sort=%2Bscheduletime"
```

My code now looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.schiphol.nl/public-flights/flights?app_id=////APPID////&app_key=////APPKEY////&scheduledate=2017-07-11&airline=CND&includelays=false&page=0&sort=%2Bscheduletime")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let urlContent = data {
            do{
            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
            print(jsonResult)
            } catch{
                print("failed")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a simple `URL` use an `URLRequest` and add the header field.

This is the Swift equivalent of the cURL syntax:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.schiphol.nl/public-flights/flights?app_id=xxxxxxx&app_key=yyyyyyyyyyyyy5&scheduledate=2017-07-11&airline=CND&includelays=false&page=0&sort=%2Bscheduletime")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.addValue("v3", forHTTPHeaderField: "ResourceVersion")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in ...
```

I made the personal data anonymous.

Note: Don't pass any options in `JSONSerialization`, the option `.mutableContainers` is completely useless in Swift.

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the `API` documents you need to set the `ResourceVersion` in the headers for the call.

The following should work:

```
    var req = URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: "https://api.schiphol.nl/public-flights/flights?app_id=//APPID//&app_key=//APPKEY//")!)
    req.setValue("v3", forHTTPHeaderField: "ResourceVersion")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req) { (data, response, error) in
        print(try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .init(rawValue: 4)))
    }.resume()
```